# Issue with a script running to lookuprows and loop through the lookup until all rows with the same ContactId have been combined into one row

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, automation

I am running the following script to lookuprows in a data extension and combine multiple rows with the same contactID into one row - but at the same time taking one column (PH_Name) from the separate rows and adding them sequentially into separate columns in the output row.

```ampscript
%%[

set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("BirthdayEmail_Combined_Audience_Split_Unique_RC",40000,"ContactId Desc", "DefaultValue", "1")
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

  for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

      set @row = row(@rows,@i) 

      set @ContactId = field(@row,"ContactId")

      OutputLine(Concat("@ContactId: ", @ContactId))

      set @rowsRC = LookupOrderedRows("BirthdayEmail_Combined_Audience_Split",40000, "RC_ContactId Desc","RC_ContactId", @ContactId)

      set @rowCountRC = rowcount(@rowsRC)

      if @rowCountRC > 0 then

        set @rowRC = row(@rowsRC,1) 
        set @RC_FirstName = field(@rowRC,"RC_FirstName")
        set @RC_LastName = field(@rowRC,"RC_LastName")
        set @RC_Email = field(@rowRC,"RC_Email")
        set @PH_Birthdate = field(@rowRC,"PH_Birthdate")
        set @PH_Role = field(@rowRC,"PH_Role")
        set @RC_AccountId = field(@rowRC,"RC_AccountId")
        set @PH_Age = field(@rowRC,"PH_Age")
        set @PH_Age_1 = Add(field(@rowRC,"PH_Age"),1)
        set @PH_FA_Id = field(@rowRC,"PH_FA_Id")
        set @RC_Role = field(@rowRC,"RC_Role")
        set @RC_EmailOptOut = field(@rowRC,"RC_EmailOptOut")
        set @FA_FinServ__SourceSystemId__c = field(@rowRC,"FA_FinServ__SourceSystemId__c")

        UpsertData('Final_Birthday_Audience',1,'RC_ContactId',@ContactId,'RC_FirstName',@RC_FirstName,'RC_LastName',@RC_LastName,'RC_Email',@RC_Email,'RC_EmailOptOut',@RC_EmailOptOut,'PH_Birthdate',@PH_Birthdate,'PH_Age',@PH_Age, 'PH_Age_1',@PH_Age_1,'PH_FA_Id',@PH_FA_Id,'RC_Role',@RC_Role,'PH_Role',@PH_Role,'RC_AccountId',@RC_AccountId,'FA_FinServ__SourceSystemId__c',@FA_FinServ__SourceSystemId__c)

        for @j = 1 to @rowCountRC do

          set @rowRC_1 = row(@rowsRC,@j) 
          set @PH_Name = field(@rowRC_1,"PH_FirstName")
          set @name = Concat('PH',@j,'_FirstName')     
          OutputLine(Concat("@name: ", @name))
          OutputLine(Concat("@value: ", @PH_Name)) 
          updateData('Final_Birthday_Audience',1,'RC_ContactId',@ContactId, @name,@PH_Name)

        next @j 

      endif

  next @i

endif

]%%
```

This all works fine when the number of rows with the same ContactID is 2 however when there are 3 rows - the PH_Name goes into the correct 3 columns, however the loop seems to continue and adds the the same names again in the next 3 columns.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: How are you running this?

Comment: Nevermind, CloudPage.  And why can't you prep this data in Query Activity?  UpdateData isn't meant for batch operations.